# How to get access to the POST button in SLComposeViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8-share-extension

On the right top side there is disabled post button. How can I change its text or enable it manually?

```
    navigationBar.rightBarButtonItem?.enabled = true
```

doesnt work

[image]

Answer (score 6):

1. It is impossible to change its text.
2. It is possible to enable or disable it at any time by call `validateContent()`:

   ```
   override func isContentValid() -> Bool {
       super.isContentValid()

       //valdate your SLComposeViewController here
   }
   ```

`isContentValid()` is called by `validateContent()`.

Comment: Man, you saved my life hahahaha tnks!